# Fitting models against residuals in the context of linear regression and regression trees

Tags: regression, self-study, cart, boosting

For predictors $X_1$ and $X_2$, and a response $Y$, two models are fit:
**Model 1**: Linear regression with $Y$ as response and $X_1$ and $X_2$ as predictors (only the linear terms).
**Model 2**: A linear regression model is fit with $Y$ as response and $X_1$ as a predictor. Using the residuals $R$ for this model, another model is fit for $R$ against $X_2$.

Apparently, **Model 1** and **Model 2** are equivalent (fitted values are the same) only when linear terms of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are involved, and $X_1$ is not correlated with $X_2$. How can this be mathematically proved?

Additionally, how does this concept relate to the boosting of regression trees, wherein the updated residuals are used as a response in successive regression trees?

Comment: Can you write it in mathematical notation and provide a source that states equivalence of fitted values? As far as i understood it I don't think it is true

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad It was mentioned in an explanation for the [quiz 7 problem](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesSciences/StatLearning/Winter2016/courseware/43d59889973b4b34a7070918f2a7bb3f/0fa2d1b669d64d4388109a95591250dc/) from the [Statistical Learning](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesSciences/StatLearning/Winter2016/info) MOOC by Hastie and Tibshirani. Please let me know if that works!

Comment: This question needs a self study tag.